# class method on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

please excuse me as my terminology may be incorrect.

I am using a plugin to make a sidebar with navigation sticky. The plugin provides this method to update calculations if needed:

> stickyBar.updateSticky()

My navigation is accordion type, meaning it has expanding sub-menus when user clicks them.

I am trying to figure out how to call the update to accommodate the changes in the elements dimensions with pure javascript.

I am figuring that the update would have to be called by scroll start events, with throttle of 500ms. Alternatively, it could be click events on a specific element ID but with a delay of about 500ms, as it has to wait for accordion transition to complete.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() { stickyBar.updateSticky(); });
```

From some searching I ended up with this code but it does not work, not to mention that it lacks the throttle. Please advise.

Comment: It's `window.addEventListener("scroll", …)`, with quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However still doesn't work.